# What were the prophecies made regarding Timothy?

Tags: 1-timothy

1 Timothy 1:18 NASB

> This command I entrust to you, Timothy, son, in accordance with the prophecies previously made concerning you, that by them you might fight the good fight…

Do we know what prophecies Paul is referring to here?

Comment: They are not recorded so we do not know

Answer (score 0):

While the scriptures don't give a direct answer, there are some possibilities.

The [study note for 1 Timothy 1:18](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwtsty/54/1#s=18&study=discover) gives the following:

> **in harmony with the prophecies that were made about you:** Paul reminds Timothy of the prophecies that had been made about him and apparently about his future role in the congregation. These prophecies were made through the operation of God’s spirit. (See study note on 1Ti 4:14) They seem to have included the authorization for Timothy’s assignment, since Paul says that **by these,** that is, the prophecies, Timothy could wage spiritual warfare against false teachers. [bold theirs]

The [study note for 1 Timothy 4:14](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwtsty/54/4#study=discover&v=54:4:14) adds:

> **through a prophecy:** This may refer to one of the prophecies made about Timothy when Paul visited Lystra during his second missionary journey. These prophecies apparently focused on Timothy’s future role in the Christian congregation. (See study note on 1Ti 1:18) Thus it was made clear that Jehovah’s spirit was directing the course that Timothy would take in his ministry. In response, the elders in Lystra readily agreed to set Timothy apart for special service and send him along with Paul.​—[Ac 16:1-5](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1001070794/61/0).  [bold theirs]

It seems that these prophecies while referenced in the Scriptures were not written.